# Elasticsearch: Define field vocabulary in mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, data-modeling

Is there a way to define (in the mapping) a set of possible values for a field?

Below I have made up an example how it could be done syntactically - not that it is possible.

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "from_ID": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "to_ID": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "property": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "values": ["a","b","c"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Like for enumerations, make sure that only those values end up in that field? The closest type that fits your need would be the [`constant_keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html#constant-keyword-field-type) but it only accepts a single value.

Comment: I guess all these things need to be formulated in an ingest pipeline?

Comment: Yes, you could probably hijack an ingest pipeline to do that job, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already guessed, a pipeline'll do the trick. The easiest version would perhaps be:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/enforce_abc
{
  "description": "Enforces a, b, or c in 'property'",
  "processors": [
    {
      "drop": {
        "if" : "ctx.property == null || !['a', 'b', 'c'].contains(ctx.property)"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: But this is called by the user who sends something to the REST-API? I want to reject all documents that do not meet the restrictions. It must be impossible to circumvent  this.

Comment: Use `index.default_pipeline`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings I'm not sure if that can be overridden my a malicious user (-> passing a different pipeline upon indexing). It's worth testing.